# How to convert a specified JSON object value to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So imagine having a JSON file like:

```
[
  { "name": "David", "code": "DA" },
  { "name": "Solomon", "code": "SO" },
  { "name": "Mirage", "code": "MI" }
]
```

How can I convert it to something like this:
`['David', 'Solomon', 'Mirage']`and
`['DA', 'SO', 'MI]`

Comment: You want 2 different array?

Comment: `a.map(item => item['name'])` and `a.map(item => item['code'])`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let data = [
 { "name": "David", "code": "DA" },
 { "name": "Solomon", "code": "SO" },
 { "name": "Mirage", "code": "MI" }
];

 const result = data.map(item => item.name);
 const result2 = data.map(item => item.code);

 console.log(result, result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = [
    { "name": "David", "code": "DA" },
    { "name": "Solomon", "code": "SO" },
    { "name": "Mirage", "code": "MI" }
 ];
  let a1= [];
  let a2= [];
  data.forEach(ei =>{
    a1.push(ei.name);
    a2.push(ei.code);
  })
  console.log(a1);
  console.log(a2);
```

Comment: If you do not wish to return value, use `.forEach` instead. `.map` returns `n` length array